# populate form input fields from xml string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form with inputs inside my page , i want to fill these fields with values of an xml string. the xml tags are the id's of the inputs.

how can i populate the form inputs from that xml string?

UPDATE:
This is myy xml tags:

```
<Main><row><sheet_number>1</sheet_number><created_by>aa        </created_by><created_at>2011-02-13</created_at><updated_by>bb        </updated_by><updated_at>2011-02-13 13:24:39.481057</updated_at><type>0</type>
```

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Please show an example of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the tags/IDs or are they generated/random? If they are constant, you could use this http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/

Instead of adding HTML, just set the values of your input elements using jQuery's `.val(value)` method: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2